# python - pack exactly 24 bits into unsigned/signed int

Tags: python

I need to send exactly 24 bits over an ethernet connection, and the program on the other end expects an unsigned int in some cases and a signed int in others (C types). I want to use the struct class, but it doesn't have a type with 3 bytes built in (like uint24_t).

Similar questions to this have been asked, but the answer always involves sending 4 bytes and padding the data packet with zeros. I cannot do this, however, since I am not writing the program which is receiving the data, and it expects *exactly* 24 bits.

I am very new at this type of programming, so help is appreciated!

Comment: Just send an array of 3 bytes... the other end can interpret that as your 24-bit value.

Comment: You might like https://code.google.com/p/python-bitstring/

Comment: try the builtin type [bytes](https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/functions.html#bytes) or [bytearray](https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/functions.html#bytearray)

Comment: @JeffMercado That sounds right to me; as long as I send 24 bits with the correct information, the other end will know what to do with it. But how do I ensure the array is 3 bytes long? I know very little about this area of programming...

Comment: Module `rawutil` https://pypi.org/project/rawutil have a support for 24-bit signed and unsigned integers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the `struct` module, create a string that contains exactly three 8-bit bytes.

```
import struct
# 24 bits: 01010101 10101010 11110000
byte1 = 0x55
byte2 = 0xaa
byte3 = 0xf0
data = struct.pack("BBB", byte1, byte2, byte3)
```

Depending on how you get the bits to send, you can define the string directly:

```
data = '\x55\xaa\xf0'
```